# Best practice to update a column of all documents to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm developing a log analysis system. The input are log files. I have an external Python program that reads the log files and decide whether a record (line) or the log files is "normal" or "malicious". I want to use [Elasticsearch Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) to append my Python program's result ("normal" or "malicious") to Elasticsearch by adding a new column called `result`. So I can see my program's result clearly via Kibana UI.

Simply speaking, my Python code and Elasticsearch both use log files as input respectively. Now I want to update the result from Python code to Elasticsearch. What's the best way to do it?

I can think of several ways:

1. Elasticsearch automatically assigns a ID (`_id`) to a document. If I can find out how Elasticsearch calculates `_id`, then my Python code can calculate it by itself, then update the corresponding Elasticsearch document via `_id`. But the question is, Elasticsearch official documentation doesn't say about what algorithm it uses to generate `_id`.
2. Add an ID (like line number) to the log files by myself. Both my program and Elasticsearch will know this ID. My program can use this ID to update. However, the downside is that my program has to search for this ID every time because it's only a normal field instead of a built-in _id. The performance will be very bad.
3. My Python code gets the logs from Elasticsearch instead of reading the log files directly. But this makes the system fragile, as Elasticsearch becomes a critical point. I only want Elasticsearch to be a log viewer currently.

So the first solution will be ideal in the current view. But I'm not sure if there are any better ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, re-structure your application so that instead of dumping plain-text to a log file you're directly writing structured log information to something like Elasticsearch. Thank me later.

That isn't always feasible (e.g. if you don't control the log source). I have a few opinions on your solutions.

1. This feels **super brittle**. Elasticsearch does not base `_id` on the properties of a particular document. It's selected based off of existing `_id` fields that it has stored (and I think also off of a random seed). Even if it could work, relying on an undocumented property is a good way to shoot yourself in the foot when dealing with a team that makes breaking changes even for its documented code as often as Elasticsearch does.
2. This one **actually isn't so bad**. Elasticsearch supports manually choosing the id of a document. Even if it didn't, it performs quite well for bulk terms queries and wouldn't be as much of a bottleneck as you might think. If you really have so much data that this could break your application then Elasticsearch might not be the best tool.
3. This solution **is great**. It's super extensible and doesn't rely on a complicated dependence on how the log file is constructed, how you've chosen to index that log in Elasticsearch, and how you're choosing to read it with Python. Rather you just get a document, and if you need to update it then you do that updating.

   Elasticsearch isn't really a worse point of failure here than before (if ES goes down, your app goes down in any of these solutions) -- you're just doing twice as many queries (read and write). If a factor of 2 kills your application, you either need a better solution to the problem (i.e. avoid Elasticsearch), or you need to throw more hardware at it. ES supports all kinds of sharding configurations, and you can make a robust server on the cheap.

One question though, why do you have logs in Elasticsearch that need to be updated with this particular normal/malicious property? If you're the one putting them into ES then just tag them appropriately before you ever store them to prevent the extra read that's bothering you. If that's not an option then you'll still probably be wanting to read ES directly to pull the logs into Python anyway to avoid the enormous overhead of parsing the original log file again.

If this is a one-time hotfix to existing ES data while you're rolling out normal/malicious, then don't worry about a 2x speed improvement. Just throttle the query if you're concerned about bringing down the cluster. The hotfix will execute eventually, and probably faster than if we keep deliberating about the best option.

Comment: I don't control the log source. All I got are log files.

Comment: My Python program is malicious behavior detection tool based on logs. I want to manually analyze the logs in Kibana first, then develop/tune my program and run the detection and generate the normal/malicious property against log files. Then append the property to Elasticsearch. It's indeed easy to upload data to Elasticsearch after I tag the data, but I cannot see the logs in Kibana before I tag them.

Comment: This architecture is only for development. The performance is important, because I want to speed up every stage in the development of the Python program.

Comment: I finally go with 2.