# Logstash: use line number of the log file as document_id

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to set the `document_id` of Logstash to the line number of the log file as below: (FYI, why I need to do this is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677832/best-practice-to-update-a-column-of-all-documents-to-elasticsearch))

```
elasticsearch { 
    host => yourEsHost
    cluster => "yourCluster"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_id => "%{lineNumber}"
}
```

For example, if the log file is:

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:10:02 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/hsdivision HTTP/1.1" 200 6291
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:11:58 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WikiSyntax HTTP/1.1" 200 7352
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:20:55 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/Main/DCCAndPostFix HTTP/1.1" 200 5253
```

I want the `document_id` of 3 documents to be 0, 1, 2 respectively.

In my scenario, one Elasticsearch index is generated from only one log file. It guarantees that such `document_id` will not be duplicated inside one index.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the answer here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-line-number-of-the-log-file-line-being-processed/40960, it is not possible for now. But there is an open issue about: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/7. So it may be possible in a future version. For know modifying file input plugin or writing your own input plugin.